# request limitation with soap on mantis

Tags: php, soap, nusoap, soap-client, mantis

i'm trying to do some request with soap on mantis . Something like that :

```
      foreach ($tabIdBugToRecup as $value) {
            $tabBugResponse[$i] = $client->mc_issue_get($username, $password, $value);
            $i++;

            }
```

when the number of request is small i've no error and the scrip work fine but when the number is big i have that error : `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/ErsSupervisor/include/req/cronBugSupport.php"`

it's why i'm asking if the number of request with soap on mantis is limited. Maybe X per secondes or?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

There are no rate limitations in the MantisBT SOAP API.

Comment: `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/ErsSupervisor/include/req/cronBugSupport.php"` but only on a big request , else i've no probleme